# Menu categorías hecho con nodos

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas,

Tengo un problema con un formulario, y es una web bastante antigua a la cuál me han dicho de hacerle unas modificaciones. Una de ellas, es hacer que el menú se mantenga abierto al pulsar y acceder a la categoría correspondiente.

El problema radica en que, eso mismo si que lo realiza al pulsar a la categoría superior, pero al pulsar en las subcategorías, no cerrandose el menu cuando no lleva a la misma. No quiero que se cierre, quiero que se mantenga abierto, categoría y subcategoría.

He intentado modificar el código, pero sin ningún exito.

No se si alguien me podrá orientar en como hacerlo, puesto que yo ya no se que más intentar. El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
// Connectem a la base de dades
include_once('includes/config.php');
if (!isset($dbh)) {
    if (!($dbh = connectPDO())) {
        $_SESSION["error_msg"] = "Error de conexión con la base de datos. (" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "," . __LINE__ . ")";
        header("Location: " . $baseURL . "error.php");
        die();
    }
}
?>
<!-- Menú de categories de producte -->
<ul id="product_categories">    
    <?php
    $SQLString = "SELECT node.IdCategory as Category, node.Description, count(parent.Description)-1 as Depth,(node.rgt-node.lft-1)/2 as Children";
    $SQLString .= " FROM product_categories node, product_categories parent";
    $SQLString .= " WHERE node.lft between parent.lft AND parent.rgt";
    $SQLString .= " AND node.Visible=1";
    $SQLString .= " GROUP BY node.IdCategory";
    $SQLString .= " ORDER BY node.lft;";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($SQLString);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $_SESSION["error_msg"] = "Error de conexión de consulta MySQL. (" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "," . __LINE__ . ")";
        header("Location: " . $baseURL . "error.php");
        die();
    }
    // Recorremos todas las categorías
    $current_depth = 1;

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $categoryURL = '';
        $toggle = '';
        // Obtenemos nodos con hijos
        if ($row['Depth'] != 0) {

            // Cerramos rama
            $jump = $current_depth - $row['Depth'];
            while ($jump > 0) {
                echo ("</ul>\n</li>\n");
                $jump = $jump - 1;
            }
            $current_depth = $row['Depth'];
            // Añadimos elemento
            if ($row['Children'] > 0) {
                $toggle = ' class="toggle-elem"';
                $add_class = 'class="' . (!empty($_GET["IdCategory"]) && $_GET["IdCategory"] == $row["Category"] ? 'sel' : '') . '" ';
                $plus = '<img class="toggle ' . (!empty($_GET["IdCategory"]) && $_GET["IdCategory"] == $row["Category"] ? 'sel-toggle' : '') . '" src="' . $baseURL . 'assets/images/plus.png" alt="Desplegar"/>';
            } else {
                $plus = '';
                //$add_class = (!empty($_GET["IdCategory"]) && $_GET["IdCategory"] == $row["Category"] ? 'class="abierto"' : 'class="cerrado"');
                $add_class = (!empty($_GET["IdCategory"]) && $_GET["IdCategory"] == $row["Category"] ? 'class="abierto"' : 'class="cerrado"');
            }
            // Generamos URL para SEO
            $categoryURL .= cleanURL($row['Description']) . "/";
            $categoryURL .= cleanURL($row["Category"]) . "";
            $categoryURL = $baseURL . "categoria/" . $categoryURL . "";

            echo ('<li' . $toggle . '><a ' . $add_class . 'href="' . $categoryURL . '"> > ' . $row['Description'] . '</a>' . $plus);
            // Rama nueva
            if ($row['Children'] > 0) {
                echo ("\n<ul " . (!empty($_GET["IdCategory"]) && $_GET["IdCategory"] == $row["Category"] ? 'class="abierto"' : 'class="cerrado"') . ">\n");
            } else {
                echo ('</li>');
            }
        }
    }

    // Cerramos el resto de ramas abiertas
    while ($current_depth > 1) {
        echo ("</ul>\n</li>\n");
        $current_depth = $current_depth - 1;
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

La web es la siguiente: https://www.servifot.com/testing/tienda . Podeis probar el menú lateral.

Saludos, y gracias de antemano

Comment: Te sugiero que gestiones la visibilidad de cada elemento con javascript y css en el frontend, te resultará mucho más sencillo.

Comment: Si, la verdad es que he estado pensado lo mismo. Pero no se bien como hacerlo con Javascript :s ¿Alguna ligera idea de por donde pondría empezar?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas a todos,

Finalmente resolvi el problema. Tras un rato indagando por la red, vi la solución en JQuery.

Os dejo mi solución al problema, por si a alguien le sirve:

```
$('ul.abierto').parent('li').parent('ul').removeClass('cerrado');
$('ul.abierto').parent('li').parent('ul').addClass('abierto');
$('ul.abierto').parent('li').parent('ul').prev('.toggle').attr('src', '/testing/assets/images/less.png');
$('ul.abierto').parent('li').parent('ul').prev('.toggle').prev('.link').addClass('sel');
```

Básicamente es determinar que elemento en el menú es anterior (es decir, padre) y ya en el padre modificar a los hermanos que necesitemos modificar. Esta imagino que es una solución de las muchas que existirán. No lo dudo.

Saludos